# Backbone.js & Handlebars.js with RESTful API

Tags: rest, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to use Backbone.js with Handlebars.js to consume and display a custome JSON API.

Data is definitely being consumed and and added into the Collection.

The template renders but the table has no data in it (one completely empty row).

How would I go about debugging this?

**Router**

```
'showStatement': function() {
    new app.StatementView({collection: new app.StatementCollection()});
}
```

**Collection**

```
app.StatementCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Transaction,
    url: 'http://localhost/api/public/out/123456/statement',

    initialize: function() {
        console.log('Init app.StatementCollection');
    }
});
```

**Model**

```
app.Transaction = Backbone.Model.extend({
    /*
    defaults: {
        vendor:   'Unknown',
        amount:   'Unknown',
        currency: 'Unknown',
        date:     'Unknown'
    }
    */
});
```

**View**

```
app.StatementView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#page',

    template: Handlebars.getTemplate( 'account_statement' ),

    initialize: function() {
        console.info(this.collection);
        this.render();
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.render);
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
        this.collection.fetch();
    },

    // render library by rendering each book in its collection
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html( this.template( JSON.stringify(this.collection.toJSON())) );  // <------ pretty sure the problem lies here?!?
        console.log('col', JSON.stringify(this.collection.toJSON()) );  // <------ the output from this is shown at the bottom
        return this;
    }
});
```

**Handlebars Template**

```
{{#if statement}}
    <h1>Your Statement</h1>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {{#each statement}}
            {{debug}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{this.vendor}}</td>
                <td>{{currency this.currency}}{{this.amount}}</td>
                <td><time class="format-date" datetime="{{this.date}}">{{this.date}}<time></td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
{{else}}
    <p class="warning">Sorry, nothing to show.</p>
{{/if}}
```

**This is what my API's JSON looks like:**

```
{"status":true,"result":[{"id":1,"vendor":"Jessops","amount":595.99,"currency":"GBP","date":"2012-11-01 04:57:04"},{"id":2,"vendor":"Starbucks","amount":6.99,"currency":"GBP","date":"2012-11-02 04:57:04"},{"id":3,"vendor":"Superdry","amount":155.99,"currency":"GBP","date":"2012-11-03 04:57:04"},{"id":6,"vendor":"Reebok Outlet","amount":205.99,"currency":"USD","date":"2012-11-05 04:57:04"}]}
```

**Output from console.log('col', JSON.stringify(this.collection.toJSON()) );**

```
col [{"status":true,"result":[{"id":1,"vendor":"Jessops","amount":595.99,"currency":"GBP","date":"2012-11-01 04:57:04"},{"id":2,"vendor":"Starbucks","amount":6.99,"currency":"GBP","date":"2012-11-02 04:57:04"},{"id":3,"vendor":"Superdry","amount":155.99,"currency":"GBP","date":"2012-11-03 04:57:04"},{"id":6,"vendor":"Reebok Outlet","amount":205.99,"currency":"USD","date":"2012-11-05 04:57:04"}]}]
```

---

**EDIT:**
I have now found that changing my render function to the following works:

```
render: function() {
    data = this.collection.toJSON();
    this.$el.html(this.template( {statement: data[0]} ));
    return this;
}
```

This suggests that my JSON output is wrong. How can I improve my JSON to reduce the need for the `[0]`?

Comment: You're stringifying your JSON before passing it into the template. You need to pass in the object directly.

Comment: or, alternatively, pass objects from the model or collection; e.g. for a model, pass the model's attributes, and for a collection, pass the collection's models to the template function - I generally prefer this in case I ever need to override the toJSON method to rearrange my object/collection to match better with what the server is expecting (generally have to do this if the server delivers me an object not in the form I need and I rearrange it)

Comment: @Nathan: I was originally passing the object directly but that didn't work either. I also tried JSON.parse() instead but that errors. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @kinakuta: How would I go about doing that? Also, is that good practice -- I really want to do this correctly if I can...

Comment: I have found a fix but would like to understand why this needed and if I can tweak the JSON output to reduce the need for a workaround? Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your API returns some 'meta' information (the `status : true` part) along with the data about the collection, and that your real data lives in the `result` array.  I think Backbone is assuming that your data is just a single item, and it putting it into an array since it is being fed into a collection object.  That's why you're needing to use `data[0]` to pull the first item out of that array.

I think you'd either want o modify your json so that the array currently returned in `result` is the top level element.  Of you'd need to find a way to tell Backbone that your data lives in the `result` element, not at the top level.